# Display first and lastname with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to make it so the user is able to enter a name and lastname and then click a send button. When that happens the name and lastname is displayed on the the screen just bellow.

The problem is that it doesn't work. Nothing happens when the user clicks the send button.

Here is how I tired it.

HTML:

```
    <body>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="MyFunction()">
    <div id="here"></div>    

<body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var first, second;
    first = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    second = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

    document.GetElementById("here").InnerHTML = first;
    document.GetElementById("here").InnerHTML = second;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7wu3gjqm/

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `document.GetElementById("here").InnerHTML` should be `document.getElementById("here").innerHTML`. Second, `getElementById` does just that, gets an element by its ID. Your inputs don't have IDs.

Comment: it should be `getElementById`! (First letter of first word is lower case, first letter of other words are upper-case)

Comment: In the JSFiddle, your console is showing the following error: `ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined`. Press F12 and go to the Console tab. If you see any errors, try to address those, as they stop all subsequent Javascript functions from running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your example worked fine after some changes :

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
```

JS:

```
myFunction = function() {
    var first = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var second = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = first+" "+second;
}
```

Find your example here : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wu3gjqm/4/).

Answer (score 5):

You wanted this as your output code:

```
document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = first + " " + second;
```

The G and I should be lower case and you should output both first and last names at the same time using string concatenation. Note though, that this will have XSS vulnerabilities.

Also, change your input name attributes to id attributes.

Comment: I should be small in innerHTML

Comment: I can't figure out what is going on in the jsfiddle app but I took the code from it and ran it in an html file and it works.

Comment: `MyFunction = function() { ... } ` not `function MyFunction() { ... }`, you're getting a console error saying `ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined`. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/7wu3gjqm/5/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById` but you dont have any element with the given Ids, I believe you've forgot to add id's to your input elements:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
```

You might also want to change `GetElementById` for `getElementById` as js is case sensitive.